# Font Identification for script typeface from embroidery

Tags: font-identification, embroidery, script-typeface

So I've used all of the "font identifying" apps on the web I could find, and none of them gave me a close matching result. I've even edited the photo so that the character color is darker than the background and erased a tiny bit of the font so the matcherator could identify the individual characters easier, but no luck.

[image: as the font appears in embroidery]

[image: darker character colour and character seperation]

Answer (score 4):

[Motion Picture](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mawns/motion-picture/) from myfonts.com.

[image: Motion Picture]

I guess the *w* from the question image is an alternative glyph for the embroidery, it looks like two letters *u* with negative tracking.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how do you know? Have you already worked with this font? Do you know/remember lots of typefaces? Are you superefficent at searching for specifics?

Comment: @BlueWizard  I work with typographies for many years, in terms of searches I know some tricks, such as putting in Google search the family, the style, and some formal characteristic. In this particular case, the letter s is very special to start a formal searching.